# How many integers in $M$ are neither odd nor multiples of $6$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble understanding this exercise from my study guide:

> Let $M = \{5k + 1 \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \le\ k \le\ 240\}$. How many integers in $M$ are neither odd nor multiples of $6$?

Given Answer:

> Let $A = \{x \in M \mid x \text{ is odd}\}$ and $B = \{y \in M \mid y \text{ is a multiple of 6}\}$.
>
> We want to find $|M - (A \cup B)|$.
>
> We see that a multiple of $6$ is even; hence $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Why is this equal to the empty set?

> Verify that,

I don't understand how to get the sets for $A$ and $B$

> $$A = \{10k + 1 \mid 0 \le k \le 23\} \qquad\text{and}\qquad
> B = \{30m + 6 \mid 0 \le m \le 7\}.$$
>
> Hence, 
>   $$|A \cup B| = 24 + 8 = 32,$$ and

Why $24$ and $8$?

> $$|M - (A \cup B)| = |M| - |A \cup B| = 241 - 32 = 209 $$

Why $241$ and $32$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My latex does not seen to be formatting properly. Does anyone know why?

Comment: You didn't enclose it in dollar signs: `$...$` for inline math, `$$...$$` for displayed math.

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/85ca1da4-327d-413e-b714-f2cfc68721cb/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Thank you Zev. As you can tell, I am new to MathJax.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the expression defining $M$ is wrong. It should be $$M=\{5k+1\,|\,k\in\mathbb{Z},\,0\leq 5k+1\leq 240\}.$$

Comment: I checked the exercise and I have it stated as it is in the study guide. But this study guide is full of errors, so you may be right in your assumption.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. If $M$ is as originally stated in the study guide, then $$M=\{1,\,6,\,11,\,16,\,21,\,26,\,\ldots,\,1\mathord{,}191,\,1\mathord{,}196,\,{1\mathord,201}\}.$$ Then, indeed, $M$ contains 241 elements as stated. But in this case, 121 of them are odd (slightly more than half of them), not 24.

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the comments, especially those from triple_sec,

- There are $241$ elements of $M_{\text{big}}=\{5k + 1 \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \le\ k \le\ 240\}$
- There are $48$ elements of $M_{\text{small}}=\{5k+1\,|\,k\in\mathbb{Z},\,0\leq 5k+1\leq 240\}$
- About half of the elements are odd and about a sixth are multiples of  $6$; none are both since any multiple of $6$ must be even, so the intersection of odd numbers and multiples of  $6$ is empty
- $121$ elements of $M_{\text{big}}$ are odd and another $40$ elements of $M_{\text{big}}$ are multiples of $6$; $121+40=161$
- $24$ elements of $M_{\text{small}}$ are odd and another $8$ elements of $M_{\text{small}}$ are multiples of $6$; $24+8=32$
- $80=241-161$ elements of $M_{\text{big}}$ are neither odd nor multiples of $6$
- $16=48-32$ elements of $M_{\text{small}}$ are neither odd nor multiples of $6$